# How to install and detect raid controller in latest Ubuntu (20+) on HP Proliant 360 Gen6

Tags: ubuntu, hp, hp-proliant

I recently purchased a set of 6 HP rack servers off of ebay for what seemed liked a fairly good deal.  The gen6 servers were launched by HP in 2009.   I am able to install and properly detect the HP Smart Array 410 Raid Controller that the servers drives are plugged into with 14.04, but having troubles with later versions of Ubuntu (does not detect block device).

Unfortunately,  Ubuntu 14.04 has reached EOL so I'd like to get something more modern onto the servers.

Any suggestions?  Are there any communities on the web where I might find technical folks trying to do something similar?

As it was suggested below there is support on 20.*, I tried my focal usb stick  again and here is what I got:

(helpful link: https://dwaves.de/2019/09/05/linux-bash-how-to-find-hardware-raid-controller-get-info-about-hardware-hp-server-get-raid-and-power-watt-usage-status-from-command-line/)

```
root@ubuntu-server:/dev# lsscsi
[0:0:0:0]    disk    JetFlash Transcend 16GB   1100  /dev/sda
(just my usb stick)
```

..

```
hpacucli ctrl all show status

Error: No controllers detected.
(using alien converted RPM)
```

..

```
03:00.0 RAID bus controller: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array G6 controllers (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array P410i
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 36
    Region 0: Memory at fb800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Region 2: Memory at fb7f0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at fb700000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
            Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
            Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
            Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
            DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <1us, L1 <8us
                    ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 116.000W
            DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr+ FatalErr+ UnsupReq-
                    RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
                    MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 4096 bytes
            DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
            LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s, Exit Latency L0s <512ns
                    ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
            LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
                    ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
            LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s (ok), Width x4 (downgraded)
                    TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
            DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis+, NROPrPrP-, LTR-
                     10BitTagComp-, 10BitTagReq-, OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt-, EETLPPrefix-
                     EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
                     FRS-, TPHComp-, ExtTPHComp-
                     AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
            DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
                     AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
            LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
                     Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                     Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
            LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
                     EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
            Vector table: BAR=0 offset=001c2000
            PBA: BAR=0 offset=001c4000
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
            UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
            UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq+ ACSViol-
            UESvrt: DLP- SDES+ TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
            CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
            CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
            AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn-
                    MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
            HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    Kernel modules: hpsa
```

..

```
root@ubuntu-server:/dev# dmesg|grep RAID
root@ubuntu-server:/dev#
```

..

```
root@ubuntu-server:/dev# dmesg|grep scsi
[    2.612058] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-5:1.0
[    3.824880] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JetFlash Transcend 16GB   1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    3.825382] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
root@ubuntu-server:/dev#
```

Comment: I hope you didn't spend too much. Those are barely worth the price of shipping any more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the [Ubuntu Server installation image](https://ubuntu.com/download/server) to install Ubuntu to an HP Smart Array controller. This image contains the necessary hpsa driver, but the regular live image, intended for desktops, does not.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  I added notes above

Comment: @Blaze Check `dmesg` (without grep!) for any relevant messages.

Comment: Issue was a number of things, resetting vram, reseating the smart array controller, and updating firmware to 6.64 from 2.0(!)

Comment: Check this out, running numpy bench on an azure instance costing me ~30$ a month and it only has 8GB (g6 box with 48GB cost me $99 shipped)

g6 box - Eigendecomposition of a 2048x2048 matrix in 11.01 s.
azure instance - Eigendecomposition of a 2048x2048 matrix in 13.01 s.

And my workloads really need 48GB per instance.